# Custom DropDownList in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to create DropDown in MVC using Custom Range as Starting is 2000 and Ending is Current Yaer.

I have this method:

```
public static void BindYearDropDown(ref DropDownList dropDown, int startYear, int endYear)
    {
        dropDown.Items.Clear();

        for (int i = startYear; i <= endYear; i++)
        {
            dropDown.Items.Add(new ListItem(ConvertTo.String(i), ConvertTo.String(i)));
        }
    }
```

How to add use this method in Controller and View

Comment: What you have in MVC so far? this seems a plain asp.net code? Go to some tutorial to see how to fill data in dropdown list. like [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/asp-net-mvc-dropdownlist-implement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code in Model

```
public string years{ get; set; }
public List<SelectListItem> yearList{ get; } = new List<SelectListItem>();
public static void BindYearDropDown(int startYear, int endYear)
{
    for (int i = startYear; i <= endYear; i++)
    {
        yearList.Add(new SelectListItem{Text = ConvertTo.String(i), Value = 
        ConvertTo.String(i)});
    }
}
```

In your controller set like this

```
//Pass value as per your requirements in BindYearDropDown()
model.BindYearDropDown(2000,endyear);
```

In your view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.years, Model.yearList, null, new { @class = "form-control", id = "years" }
```